# Setting track points from Mocha to a solid makes it very small

Tags: after-effects, tracking

I'm a newbie to all of this so please bare with me.

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBNMQNIISUg) tutorial.

After tracking the movement with Mocha the tracking data is copied to AE.
If I copy the data and past it onto a solid the solid becomes very small. 
I have no idea what causes this. Because of the images that are used on the solid I am not able to scale it up.

See before:
[image]

And After:
[image]

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Unbelievable,

Right after I asked the question I found the solution online.
After tracking in Mocha make sure you click the "Align selected surfaces" button.
I had to search for it but here it is:
[image]

After this you can copy your tracking data and paste it in AE.